# Getting non-deterministic results running EfficientnetB0/Efficinetnet-lite0 models on GPU (using tensorflow-gpu 2.2)

Tags: tensorflow, random-seed, non-deterministic, efficientnet

The following random seeds were set

```
SEED = 1
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
```

The following Environmental Variables were set `TRUE`

```
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = TRUE
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = TRUE
```

What could possibly be the source of the issue?

Comment: What do you mean non-deterministic results? Did you tried checking model on CPU? Please can you share reproducible code to replicate your issue, so that we can help you. Thanks!